# Passing file name from UploadNamer to UploadListener in Symfony v4.1 with OneUpUploaderBundle

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, blueimp, oneupuploaderbundle

### Introduction

I am using `Symfony v4.1.*` with [OneUpUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle).
I need to set unique name for each uploaded file - that works.

I have `tree structure`, that contains uploaded files.
In order to manage files in the tree i have multiple properties.
Some of them are:

1. **itemName** (transliterated file name + counter + unique_sting)
2. **itemOriginalName** (transliterated file name + counter)
3. **itemExtension** (file extension - for example `.txt` or `.a` if directory)
4. **itemSortValue** (file extension + transliterated file name + counter + unique_sting)

`ItemSortValue` assures that tree branches (fields) are sorted alphabetically.

### Problem

> I need also to persist information about uploaded file in database.
>   For that purpose i need to get each `complete file name` that is managed by `UploadNamer` in my `UploadListener` in `onPostUpload` event.

```
path/to/file/my_file_name(counter)_{time}_{uniqueString}.extension
```

I need to save same unique file name to the database.
Yet the problem that i am facing is - i do not know and can not find just how to pass information from `UploadNamer` to `uploadListener`.

I tried to use `$this->originalName` but it did not yield positive results.

### Question

How do i pass a value from `UploadNamer` to `UploadListener` *(onPostUpload event)* in `Symfony v4.1` with `OneUpUploaderBundle`?

### CODE:

> custom namer

```
public function name(FileInterface $file)
{
    $upload_file_path = $this->ultraHelpers->getUploadableFilePath();

    $unique_string = $this->ultraHelpers->getUniqueString(true);

    $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file_info = $this->ultraHelpers->filterFileInfoFromFilename($file_name);

    return sprintf('%s/%s_%s.%s',
        $upload_file_path,
        $this->ultraText->transliterateText($file_info['name']),
        $unique_string,
        $file_info['extension']
    );
}
```

> `UploadNamer` example output

```
dir1/dir2/dir3/my_file_name_1539617029_23bf16f962c658103f10ece7d3ba7a88.txt

that corresponds to
path/to/file/my_file_name(counter)_{time}_{uniqueString}.extension
```

> my `UploadListener`

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use App\UltraHelpers\UltraFileTree;
use App\UltraHelpers\UltraHelpers;
use App\UltraHelpers\UltraText;
use DateTime;
use App\Entity\FileTree;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PreUploadEvent;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostUploadEvent;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class UploadListener
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    protected $entityManager;

    /**
     * @var SessionInterface
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    protected $container;

    /**
     * @var UltraHelpers
     */
    protected $ultraHelpers;

    /**
     * @var UltraText
     */
    protected $ultraText;

    /**
     * @var UltraFileTree
     */
    protected $ultraFileTree;

    protected $originalName;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, SessionInterface $session, ContainerInterface $container, UltraHelpers $ultraHelpers, UltraText $ultraText, UltraFileTree $ultraFileTree)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->ultraHelpers = $ultraHelpers;
        $this->ultraText = $ultraText;
        $this->ultraFileTree = $ultraFileTree;
        $this->originalName = [];
    }

    public function onUpload(PreUploadEvent $event)
    {
        $file = $event->getFile();

        $file_info = $this->ultraHelpers->filterFileInfoFromPath($file->getClientOriginalName());
        $this->originalName = $this->ultraText->transliterateText($file_info['name']);

        $response = $event->getResponse();
        $message = [
            'error' => 'none'
        ];
        $response->addToOffset($message, array('files'));
    }

    public function onPostUpload(PostUploadEvent $event)
    {
        $now_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $repo_file_tree = $this->entityManager->getRepository('App:FileTree');
        $repo_project = $this->entityManager->getRepository('App:Project');
        $repo_whereabouts = $this->entityManager->getRepository('App:Whereabouts');

        $whereabouts = $this->session->get('whereabouts');
        $my_whereabouts = $repo_whereabouts->getWhereabouts($whereabouts);

        // get project object
        $project_obj = $repo_project->findOneBy(array('id' => $my_whereabouts['project_id']));
        // get current directory object
        $node_selected_obj = $repo_file_tree->findOneBy(array('id' => $my_whereabouts['node_selected_id']));

        $file = $event->getFile();
        $file_size = $file->getSize();

        $current_file_name_parts = $this->ultraHelpers->getFileNameParts($this->originalName);
        $postfix_txt = $this->ultraHelpers->getFileNamePostfixTxt($current_file_name_parts['name'], $my_whereabouts['node_selected_id']);

        $file_tree = new FileTree();
        $file_tree->setItemOriginalName($current_file_name_parts['name'] . $postfix_txt);
        $file_tree->setItemName($current_file_name_parts['name'] . $postfix_txt);
        $file_tree->setItemExtension('.'. $current_file_name_parts['extension']);
        $file_tree->setItemSortValue('.'. $current_file_name_parts['extension'] .'.'. $current_file_name_parts['name'] . $postfix_txt);
        $file_tree->setItemSize($file_size);
        $file_tree->setUpdatedAt(new DateTime($now_date_time));
        $file_tree->setIsFile(true);
        $file_tree->setParent($node_selected_obj);
        $file_tree->setProject($project_obj);

        $this->entityManager->persist($file_tree);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        $this->entityManager->clear();

        // pārkārto FileTree koka zaru ievērojot jaunpievienoto failu
        $file_tree_branch_node_id = $repo_file_tree->getOneFileTreeNode($my_whereabouts['node_selected_id']);
        $this->ultraFileTree->reorderFileTreeBranch($file_tree_branch_node_id);

        $event->getResponse();
    }
}
```

### Conclusion

Please advise.

Thank You for your time and knowledge.

### Update 1

Added [github issue](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/issues/348) (#348) in OneupUploaderBundle on GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can get file name from namer with `$file->getPathname` in the `eventListener`.

I had sneaky error in code block that followed, thus it led me believe there was a problem with file name...